# Set a javascript object property in a constructor with mongoose.find() method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I'm trying to set to set my `_docs` property of the `Flight` Object with the returned docs from my mongoose query and then define two others properties based on the `_docs` property but i'm not able to do it because it happens asynchronously. I have tried callbacks, promises and npm async but i don't get it to work.

I'm relatively new to JavaScript and have some problems to correctly understand asynchronous concepts. I'm using node.js.

Here is what i'm trying to do:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://*******:******@localhost:27017/monitoring');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/monitoring', {username: '********',password: '*******'});
var VolDoc = require('./model/voldoc.js');


var Flight = function(flightId) {
    this._flightId = flightId;
    this._docs = VolDoc.find({_id: flightId}, {}, function(e, docs) {
        return docs; //this._docs should be the same than docs!
        //here or outside of the query i want do define a BEGIN and END property of the Flight Object like this : 
        //this._BEGIN = docs[0].BEGIN;    
        //this refers to the wrong object!
        //this._END = docs[0].END;
    });
    //or here :  this._BEGIN = this._docs[0].BEGIN;
    //this._END = this._docs[0].END
};

var flight = new Flight('554b09abac8a88e0076dca51');
// console.log(flight) logs: {_flightId: '554b09abac8a88e0076dca51',
                             //_docs:
                             //and a long long mongoose object!!
                             }
```

I tried  lot of different ways. So when it doesn't return the mongoose object i get only the `flightId` in the object and the rest is `undefined` because the program goes on without waiting for the query to be completed.

Can anybody help me to solve this please?

Comment: use event dispatcher and listener in case of asynchronous call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

```
require('async');

var Flight = function(flightId)
{
  this._flightId = flightId;
};

var flight = new Flight("qwertz");
async.series([
  function(callback){
    VolDoc.find({_id:self._flightId},{}, function(e, docs)
    {
      flight._docs = docs;
      flight._BEGIN = docs[0].BEGIN;    
      flight._END = docs[0].END;
      callback(e, 'one');
    });                                                        
  },
  function(callback){
    // do what you need flight._docs for.
    console.dir(flight._docs);
    callback(null, 'two');
  }
]);
```

Comment: I just tried it but i still have the problem with the asynchronousity, when i try to console.log(flight._docs) i get undefined because the query takes a while and the program goes on without waiting for the query to be completed.

Comment: I fear your concept is wrong. It is the meaning of reactive/asynchronous  programming that things go on while you wait for e.g. a value read from a database. If you want to synchronize your mongoose acces with some other part of you program, you have to take the VolDoc.find call out of your Flight constructor function and synchronize it. You can use async https://github.com/caolan/async or Kris Kowolskis Q Lib https://github.com/kriskowal/q to support you.

Comment: I eddited my answer. This is untested code. There might be errors. It should give you a hint.

Comment: OK thank you very much it works, but is there no way to define all the properties directly inside constructor? so that i only have to enter new Flight('qwertz') and my Object is ready?

Comment: No there is not, because mongoose is asynchron. A call to the find method does not block and wait until data is available. That's why you provide a so called callback function which is called when the data is available. I do not know a synchronous call to the mongodb.